# Why using drop_out layer with tensorflow cause memory allocation error?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a simple network with a few layers (3 conv + 1 fully connected). The last convolution layer output a tensor of shape 32x32x192 and is followed by a fully connected layer of output dim 4096. Without dropout layer, this network have a normal memory footprint. No more than 2G on my PC. But when I had a dropout layer between the last convolution and the fully connected layer, there's a memory allocation error. The total memory of my PC is 16G.

Comment: I am having the same problem now. Have you found any fix?

Comment: Is this problem still reproducible with TF 1.0?

Comment: Which optimizer are you using? And from this issue, appears dropout layer may be making copies? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4309